# Проверка галочки лучшая цена

Tags: веб-программирование, opencart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данных товара на opencart можно поставить галочку, мол лучшая цена.

Как в коде проверить наличие этой галочки? Что-то подобное:

```
{% if product. ... %}
...
{% endif %}
```